# What to pass as a "capsule" argument in Python, after wrapping a C++ library with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pybind11

There is a library in C++, I wrapped it with pybind11 for use in Python. This library has a method that takes a parameter of type `void *` as input.

```
ssize_t saRead(uint16_t sa, void *data, size_t size, SA_Mode_t mode = SA_WRITE);
```

This itself is an overloaded method, so in pybind11 I wrapped it as:

```
.def("saRead", py::overload_cast<uint16_t, void *, size_t, lib_ta1::RT::SA_Mode_t>(&lib_ta1::RT::saRead))
```

Python indicates that an argument of type `capsule` must be passed as the input to this method.

```
saRead(self: ta1.RT, arg0: int, arg1: capsule, arg2: int, arg3: lib_ta1::RT::SA_Mode_t) -> int
```

As a result, tell me what should I convey as a `capsule`? Or do I need to wrap this method differently in pybind11?

Comment: What is the actual data inside this `void *` argument? What I recommend is to wrap `saRead` with a more _bindable_ function (e.g. use `std::vector<double>` instead of the `void*` if your buffer contains doubles) and then let pybind to bind the wrapped one.